# [pool release]; Crash my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my app i have a loop that move on array of `UIImage` and make stuff with this images.
the loop work in the background Thread so in the start of the function i put :

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
```

and in the end

```
[pool release];
```

In the loop i create `UIImage` so i need to release it because it give me a memory warning if i am not make a release.

When the app finish the loop and get to the

```
[pool release];
```

it give me `BAD_ACCESS` error and crash the app.

Edit

---

This is the methods in the loop

```
        UIImage *tmp = [image rotate:UIImageOrientationRight];
        //do some stuff with this image
        [tmp release];
```

This is the rotate method:

```
    UIImage*           copy = nil;
    CGRect             bnds = CGRectZero;
    UIImage*           copy = nil;
    CGContextRef       ctxt = nil;
    CGImageRef         imag = self.CGImage;
    CGRect             rect = CGRectZero;
    CGAffineTransform  tran = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    rect.size.width  = CGImageGetWidth(imag);
    rect.size.height = CGImageGetHeight(imag);

    bnds = rect;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bnds.size);
    ctxt = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

switch (orient)
{
    case UIImageOrientationLeft:
    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
    case UIImageOrientationRight:
    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
        CGContextScaleCTM(ctxt, -1.0, 1.0);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(ctxt, -rect.size.height, 0.0);
        break;

    default:
        CGContextScaleCTM(ctxt, 1.0, -1.0);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(ctxt, 0.0, -rect.size.height);
        break;
}

CGContextConcatCTM(ctxt, tran);
CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect, imag);

copy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

if (imag) {
    CFRelease(imag);
}

return copy;
```

Comment: Can you post code for how you initialize your UIImage?

Comment: Yep, when you drain the pool that releases everything that has been autoreleased since the pool was created.  This can lead to two problems:  1) Releasing something that has already been released -- this usually results in an error message to that effect.  2) Releasing something that really needs to hang around, like one of your UI objects.  This usually results in a very unuseful crash message.  Sometimes the specific cause is fairly obvious, other times it's really a challenge to figure out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're over-releasing your image after rotating it.

```
    UIImage *tmp = [image rotate:UIImageOrientationRight];
    //do some stuff with this image
    [tmp release]; // Here
```

`UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` returns an autoreleased object, so you don't need to call release on it after you return it.

The crash happens when releasing the NSAutoreleasePool because the last `-release` is not sent until it gets drained and sends the correct release call to your object that was previously and wrongly released by you.

Comment: Beat me to it. His questions sounded like an over-released object, the code proves it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're releasing some objects you create and don't own between the time you create the pool and release it again.

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 2];
// Your string now has a retain count of one, but it's autoreleased. So when the pool
// gets released it'll release the string

[s release];
// You decrease the retain count to zero, so the object gets destroyed
// s now points to a deallocated object

[pool release];
// The pool gets destroyed, so it tries to send a release method to your string. However,
// the string doesn't exist anymore so an error occurs.
```

Comment: but if i not release the object my app get memory warning

Comment: The first line of this is correct, the example is not.  First, absolute retain counts are useless;  don't think of 'em.  Secondly, `NSString` is a statically allocated object;  retain/release is a no-op.

Comment: Why is thinking of absolute retain counts useless? Fixed the static allocated object thingy

Answer (score 0):

I think your crash is probably related to when the autorelease pool releases the UIImages, not from releasing the autorelease pool.

Comment: yeah, remove the manual [ release] (or CFRelease()) calls and let the autorelease pool take care of it